# Typescript Declaration Files for Local JS Files

Tags: javascript, typescript, declaration, type-declaration, declaration-files

I am trying add typings for our Javascript files at work while we are in the process of converting to Typescript. However, I can not get the declaration files to be recognized.

Here is my file structure

- js

  - Foo.js
- typings

  - Foo

    - index.d.ts
- index.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

**Foo.js**

```
module.exports = function Foo() {
   return 'Bar';
 };
```

**index.d.ts**

```
export = Foo;

declare function Foo(): string;
```

**index.ts**

```
import Foo = require('./js/Foo')

console.log(Foo());
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./typings"],
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["typings/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fail",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Here is repo to reproduce my problem

https://github.com/erisman20/typings_help

Edit: Here is there error I get

`error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './js/Foo.js'. '....../js/Foo.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only ways to provide declarations for a relative import such as `'./js/Foo'` are to actually have the declaration file at the import path (plus `.d.ts` or `/index.d.ts`) or to have it virtually at the import path based on your `rootDirs` option.  Neither `typeRoots` nor `baseUrl`/`paths` comes into play in this scenario: `baseUrl`/`paths` only affects module resolution for "non-relative" paths, and `typeRoots` can be used to get TypeScript to load files but does not affect the relationship between import paths and files at all.

The simplest solution would be to put a `Foo.d.ts` file in the same directory as `Foo.js`.  If you want to keep the typings in a separate directory, then you can add `"rootDirs": ["js", "typings"]` to `tsconfig.json`.  That change is enough to make your example work for me, though I find it confusing to have corresponding `Foo.js` and `Foo/index.d.ts` files and would encourage you to be consistent in your use of subdirectories, i.e., either switch to `Foo/index.js` on the JavaScript side or switch to `Foo.d.ts` on the TypeScript side.

Comment: what if I add `"js/*": ["js/*"]` to the paths and reference the js file using `import Foo = require('js/Foo')` ? Then the rootDirs no longer works

Comment: If you want to `require('js/Foo')` (which assumes proper configuration of your module loader or bundler), then your `paths` setting should be `"js/*": ["js/*", "typings/*"]` so that TypeScript looks at `typings/Foo`.  (You can omit the `"js/*"` target if you have `allowJs` disabled or you have declaration files for all of your JavaScript files, because in either of those cases, it would not be used.)